# VBA Run-Time error '9' (Subscript out of range) on transfered in worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

This is my first post and I new to programming in VBA. I have a large excel file where I am trying to create a macro to delete multiple tabs. My code is as followed it works as I am prompted with a do I wish to permanently delete:

```
Option Explicit

Sub delSheet()

Worksheets("sheet2").Delete

End Sub
```

However when I transfer in a tab (tab name is "sheet92') from another file I get this error using the same code

```
Option Explicit

Sub delSheet()

Worksheets("sheet92").Delete

End Sub
```

What is causing the code to delete the sheet2 which is the tab that I created within opening a .xlsb file and creating a new sheet vs. the error message on copying into the file from an existing file? Thank you advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear, but you probably have to reference the correct workbook, like this:

```
Workbooks("file.xlsx").Worksheets("sheet92").Delete
```

If the workbook is not already active, giving only `Worksheets("sheet92")` won't work.

Comment: I changed the code to reference the workbook. The workbook name is WW OCOGS Jun 17 Pass 2 Test Book and the new code I entered is `Workbooks("WW OCOGS Jun 17 Pass 2 Test Book .xlsm").Worksheets("sheet92").Delete`. However, I am now getting the error message, Compile error Sub or function not defined. Also when I am entering the text, after I enter the workbooks code I get the autofill options such as toggling active sheet or worksheet, but after I enter the worksheet link the VBA does not give me any option to autoselect the next item in the code string.

Comment: @JSBach Works for me. Did you forget an "s" or something? I don't have the autoselect after Worksheets either, but this is not a problem. Does it work if you replace "Delete" with "Activate"?

Comment: @JSBach For reference, all methods of the class Worksheet are described [here in MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheet-object-excel). Notice that the class is Worksheet, but to select a specific one you write `Worksheets("name")`, with an "s". The `Worksheets` collection (which refers to the **active** workbook) is described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Excel-VBA/articles/worksheets-object-excel), while the `Workbooks` collection (of all open workbooks) is described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/workbooks-object-excel)

Comment: When I changed the Method in the code from `worksheets("sheet92").Select` or `worksheets("sheet92").Copy` I still receive the same Run-time error 9. However, I am able to activate the workbook using the `Workbooks("WW OCOGS Jun 17 Pass 2.xlsm").Close` and the file prompts me if I want to close. I can also use the 'worksheet.Add` and it adds a new sheet. I am again unsure why this file does not allow me to delete sheets. Thank you for your continued help and I hope we can solve this together.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my first progroamming bug! I was using the wrong name, I was using the field (name) vs. the actual name of the tab, I took a screen capture here !https://i.stack.imgur.com/2J0C2.jpg! once I used name Sheet1 I was able to delete. Thank you for your help @cub